# Grouping in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Can you please advise how to make this special grouping in SQL
from this table

```
id  FromDate    ToDate          UPC         price   IsGroupSpecial  
3   2013-12-27  2013-12-30  6400000087492   315.00  1           
2   2013-12-27  2013-12-31  6400000087492   405.00  0
```

Need to select all with min price but the id is not necessarily minimum - the id should be taken from that row where IsGroupSpecial= 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly

```
select UPC, min(price), x.id
from table t1
cross apply (select id from table t2 where t2.IsGroupSpecial =0 and t1.UPC=t2.UPC) X 
group by UPC, x.id
```

Comment: Right, this is expected result. Just slightly modified your query so that it accepts situations when in group thereis only 1 row:

Comment: select UPC, min(price), COALESCE(x.id,t1.id) as id
from test_table t1
outer apply (select id from test_table t2 where t2.IsGroup =0 and t1.UPC=t2.UPC) X 
group by UPC, COALESCE(x.id,t1.id)

Comment: Thank you. I've never used 'apply' by the way. Thanks for broadening my horizons))

Answer (score 1):

I think this type of query is what you're looking for. If you're just looking for all records that have the minimum price than a group by clause is not necessary.

```
select *
from table
where price = (select min(price) from table))
```

Comment: Thanks, but not so easy)) This just return me 1st row . The result set must be 2   2013-12-27  2013-12-30  6400000087492   315.00  0

Comment: I'm sorry but I wouldn' t hurry up to add 'minus' to my question. With your solution the result set will contain NO rows, Whereas I need some, Please reread question once again . I think about quereing this table under different aliases. Just probably someone has another idea

Comment: If the minimum value must be among the IsGroupSpecial = 0, then it should be `WHERE price = (SELECT MIN(price) FROM table WHERE IsGroupSpecial = 0)) AND IsGroupSpecial = 0`

Comment: No, min price of group (in this case these 2 rows forms a group) but the id should be taken from that row where IsGroupSpecial = 0 So ., not so easy)) that is why I'm here//....

Comment: Would you give a few more rows of sample data and show the results you are looking for based on the sample?